# Woocommerce Global Tax Calculations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am setting up an online store with the Wordpress X theme and have been doing research on tax calculations and cannot find the correct answer for worldwide tax calculations. I want to be able to sell products to anyone in the world. Is there an extension for this or do I need to enter each tax rate by state, country AND city? How does this work?

Thank you I appreciate any info.

Comment: This question might be off-topic for this site.

Comment: Oh sorry. I came across other topics of Woocommerce and didn't think twice about posting. My bad.